# probability that a random vector after normlization has exactly k elements s.t the sum of these elements is less then r

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

Assume that $V$ is a vector $V=[v_1, v_2, .., v_n]$ where each element is drawn independently forom a uniform normal distribution $v_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^{2})$. Suppose that $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$. Let X be a normalized version of $V$ so $X=\frac{V}{|V|}$. What is the probability that there is only 1 possible selection ok $k$ elemnets out of $n$ s.t their sum is less than a constant $r$. This means that any other $k$ selection will need to have its value larger then r.

This problem is really breaking my head. I assume that after the normalisation $x$s will not be independent random variables any more but I have no idea how to even start this.

Comment: You're just choosing a unit vector uniformly randomly on the unit sphere. So the question amounts to what fraction of the volume of the unit sphere satisfies the given condition. The Gaussians are a distraction; all you need to know about Gaussians to solve this problem is that their distribution depends multiplicatively on $x^2$ so that if you have several of them their joint distribution depends only on $r^2$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @joriki I don't quite get your last sentance. But calcualting the fraction of volume of a high dimensional sphere is really not staright forward so I hoped there is a simplier way

Comment: About the last sentence: Each Gaussian has a factor $\exp(-\alpha x_i^2)$, and when you multiply the densities for the independent distributions, these can all be combined into $\exp(-\alpha r^2)$ (where $r^2=\sum_ix_i^2$ is the squared difference from the origin), so the density is spherically symmetric and in (hyper)spherical coordinates only depends on $r$ and not on the angular variables. (Sorry, I wrote $x$, thinking of coordinates; in your notation these are the $v_i$.)

Comment: This is why if a 0 mean normal distribution with unit variance is used we will have $r=\sqrt{d}$? I read it somewhere but it is very interesting to see the reason behind it.

Comment: What's $d$ here?

Comment: ups sorry I meant $\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is the number of dimensions

Comment: @jorki Am I right on this $r= \sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In a normal distribution, $r$ isn't a constant. Do you mean something like that $r$ is of the order of $\sqrt n$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78627/discussion-between-daleksupreme-and-joriki).